# Get appExchange package ID

Tags: salesforcedx, appexchange

I work with SFDX and to install or include dependence with other package i need it's id. I know that one can get it when is on screen where one pick for whom the package should be installed, it is in URL.

But i am trying to do with this one: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000DpZt6EAF

and one you click the get it link i get to send message to the package owner so he/she could help me with installation. So eventually i will get that ID from them probably but! Maybe there is some other better way of doing that?

Comment: are you looking for a way to find ID of package which is already installed to an org?

Comment: Nope. It is package id that will allow me to install the package with sfdx force:package:install --package <Id here> comment.

Comment: In my case if I needed package id to install in scratch org which was installed on production, I used a command to list packages in an org. In your case you are trying to find Id of package from AppExchange, so you just need to install it manually once and then find the id and install it later on other orgs using that Id by SFDX

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The AppExchange License ID and the Package ID are not correlated together. There is no way to determine a package ID from its AppExchange Listing ID. This is because one listing could be associated with multiple versions (and the listing can be updated at any time by the package publisher). Once installed, you can use DX's `force:package:installed:list` to determine which version and Package ID is installed, but not beforehand. Note that "a0N" is a custom object prefix (all custom objects Ids start with `aXX`). As you can see, the listings are actually just a custom object in a specific org (I believe org62, but I could easily be wrong). You will need to install the package at least once, *or* have access to its internal installation URL, which can be obtained from the vendor producing the package.

Comment: thx :) for help this solved my problem